# GoDaddy virtual dedicated servers

Tags: web-server, godaddy

I have been using a GoDaddy VDS for about a month now. I have had several issues with the server and every time the support reps tell me I need to upgrade the server. I basically have Windows, IIS7.5 and SQL Server express running and sometimes the VDS is very slow to reply to web requests.

I want the site to go live soon and I'm very nervous about going live with GoDaddy. Is it me or are GoDaddy VDS server just slow and unreliable? Should I invest in a better VDS plan with godaddy or just chuck that and move to another host?

Comment: How much DO you pa? It could be everything, from too small a server to severely stupid programming (like a database without indices). Seen both. Without context a sensible answer makes no sense.

Comment: @TomTom - I'm not asking you to help me solve the issue. I'm just asking if they are systemically slow and unreliable, or is it just this specific instance.

Comment: But taht really is subjective. You dont give any hard evidence. I haver seen crap code tke a decent server to a standstill. How much slower than your local workstation are they?

Comment: GoDaddy will virtually always tell you something is your fault, even when it's blatantly false.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy's business model has historically involved high volume low overhead products. They typically are not the guys developing new solutions or pushing the technical envelope to make stand out products. They usually ride whatever wave is out there and try to cash in by bringing it to the masses. While some people would argue they are a great registrar, I would say their track record as a hosting company, particularly when it comes to security, is sub-par.

With that in mind, if the product you plan to go live with is of significant importance to you, I would consider moving it elsewhere.

As a side note, I think their use of the term "virtual dedicated server" is just a marketing twist on the more widely used term "virtual private server" or VPS. The fact that they play with their terminology like that shows they are marketing experts, not technology leaders. The world of cloud computing is full of buzzwords that don't mean much, but trying to work the word "dedicated" into a virtual computing offering is pretty out there.

Comment: Yeah. Virtual Dedicated is like vegetarian argentian beef steak. Does not add up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not interested in all the marketing hype. They are marketing master-minds, but that is beside the point. What I am interested in finding out is, are they systemically slow or is it some kind of miss configuration or are the virtual machine specs not heigh enough.

Comment: My point was that for a mission to be successful, you need a provider with that can service your problems, not just answer every question with "upgrade your plan". You haven't given us enough data to judge whether your current instance type should be adequate or whatever your software architecture and code have problems that are leading to slowdowns. All we can provide is subjective feedback on them as a provider in general.

Answer (score 0):

Their VDS (cloud servers) is not VPS.  The cloud offering allows you to setup private networks between your servers, has a load balancer / port forwarding, and allows snapshots and backups.

Its very similar to running your own xen / hyper-v enviornment with a very simple interface.

Here is my experience.
Godaddy + Inexpensive for cloud compared to amazon, axure and rackspace
Free load balancer is nice.
Storage is cheap, although we mount amazon s3 because its cheaper.
bandwidth is cheap, but use a cdn like max cdn and its even cheaper.

its a good deal, for getting everything setup quickly.
The catch is you cannot export images.

If you have the time to dedicate it might be worth leasing a physical server and running your own cloud on top of it.   XenServer is a good choice for this.