# CentOs 7 firewall, without iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall, centos7

A client of mine purchased a GoDaddy "dedicated" server, which is bad enough on it's own. But they are providing a malfunctioning product, and refuse to fix it.

When CentOS 7 is running under a Virtuozzo or OpenVZ virtual container, without netfilter full, iptables refuses to boot up.
`Journalctl -xe` states `iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 14 failed`
Which if you dig further indicates that the ebtables module is not running, stating `The kernel doesn't support the ebtables 'nat' table.`

So in short, iptables doesn't work, cannot be made operable, and the hosting environment cannot be changed to support it.

**My question is, are there any alternative non iptables based firewall software that can be used as a replacement?**
Right now the ports cannot be blocked, and services cannot be restricted to an ip whitelist for safety. It's wide open.

Ref: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=54469&start=20
See also(godaddy "vds"): [GoDaddy virtual dedicated servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/267634/godaddy-virtual-dedicated-servers)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Is it a dedicated server or not? Where did OpenVZ come into the picture?

Comment: Tell me about it. GoDaddy LIES to it's customers, their dedicated servers are INFACT virtual. I have video evidence recording it.

Comment: Well you're screwed. Only Godaddy can fix that (on the HN) and I bet they won't be willing to do so.

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation. I debated running everything under docker, but that too, is restricted (overlay2 driver for filesystem). Only thing I can think of is some kind of all-port proxy software to manage requests on the entire interface -- but I can't think of such a software. Maybe have to write it myself.  This is why you don't host with B-rate quality companies.

Comment: FYI for any onlookers in future. I decided to make use of Cloudflare Access + Argo Tunnel. After changing all the services to run on the [lo] loopback interface (127.0.0.1), they are inaccessible publicly. But via cloudflared, they work fine and are protected. Even SSH!  FTP will be the only attack vector, other than O/S zero-day attacks.